# using stomp sockjs with spring 4 getting this error sUncaught TypeError: onreceive is not a function(…)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I  am getting this error on using Stomp, sockjs with spring 4 using tomcat 7.0.56:

Uncaught TypeError: onreceive is not a function(…) stomp.js;

Please canyone can help?